# EF Core Add-Migration fails with System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, ef-core-3.1

I am using Ef Core 3.1 and I have the following simple DBContext.

```
public class UserDbContext : DbContext
{
    public UserDbContext (DbContextOptions<UserDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
    public DbSet<User> Users{ get; set; }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
    }
}
```

And here is my Startup:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddOptions();
        services.Configure<Settings>(Configuration);
        var appSettings = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IOptions<Settings>>().Value;
        services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options => 
            options.UseSqlServer(appSettings.DataStoreSettings.ConnectionString));
        services.AddControllers();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
        using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
        {
            var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DbContext>();
            context.Database.Migrate();
        }
    }
}
```

When starting my website, the database gets created successfully with only dbo.__EFMigrationsHistory table.

When I try to add a migration using:

```
Add-Migration Initial -c UserDbContext -Verbose
```

I get the following Error:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationException: Unable to
>   create an object of type 'UserDbContext'. For the different patterns
>   supported at design time, see
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728  --->
>   System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined
>   for type 'UserDbContext'.

Adding a parameterless constructor to my context results:

> No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A
>   provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring
>   method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider.
>   If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type
>   accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and
>   passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

I am not sure why `Add-Migration` is not working, can't I use Dependency Injection with EF core, if I need to use migrations?

Comment: And why you cannot add an parameterless constructor, as the exceptions says ?

Comment: There is a space after the UserDbContext that shouldn't be there: `DbContextOptions<UserDbContext >`

Comment: @Holger as mentioned in my question, if I add I will get a different error

Comment: Could you add your program.cs please? EF migrations expects for a certain format, we could check if this is the error

Comment: The second error when you add the parameterless constructor is exactly what it says -- you aren't setting up a database provider in `OnConfiguring`.

Comment: The connection string need to come from somewhere. In worst case your parameterless constructor must set it's own connection string to a static string. Usually it comes from app.config and you set the connection string to a variable name only. But this works only if you Context is in your startup project.

Comment: He is configuring it with AddDbContext, so, it is more work to ask him to configure it again just so he can use migrations, he just need to be sure he is using the expected format for EF in the program.cs

Comment: @rekiem87 I added program.cs to question

Comment: Seems like you shouldn't have the override to `OnConfiguring` if you're using `AddDbContext`?

Comment: @Herohtar tries without it as well, nothing changed

Comment: Also OnModelCreating should not be called, or, if you need to add something there, do not forget to call
base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); before anything, still the same error?

Comment: @rekiem87 yes, still same

Comment: Ok, I am lost, everything seems fine to me, I have your almost exact setup and is working for me, if no one can help maybe I can check with more time in the night (at work right now) I really hope someone can help you before

Comment: it is driving me mad as well :D thank you

Answer (score 1):

The issue was in registering `DbContext` in IOC.

Replacing:

```
services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options => 
            options.UseSqlServer(appSettings.DataStoreSettings.ConnectionString));
```

With:

```
services.AddDbContext<UserDbContext>(options => 
            options.UseSqlServer(appSettings.DataStoreSettings.ConnectionString));
```

Fixed it.